# Retrieving Data From A MYSQL Table to Insert into Another Table Along With Other Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with some tables intended to keep tags for images. I when The images are uploaded to the server there is an input form that has a few hidden fields as well as one input field allowing the user to add comma delimited tags. Everything works fine but the `target url table` is not receiving the data. I am not getting an errors and I am thinking this is because my database insert query must be messed up. Assuming so because I am trying to grab data from other tables and use it in the query that goes into the `target url table`

Instead of creating a wall of code here I am pretty sure its in my query so I will start with that.

```
function addTags($tag_type_id, $tag_target_name, $tag_target_url, $tags){

        /*** explode the tag string ***/
            $tag_array = explode(',', $tags);

            /*** loop of the tags array ***/
            foreach( $tag_array as $tag_name )
            {
                /*** insert tag into tags table ***/
                $tag_name = strtolower(trim($tag_name));

                $databaseQuery = "INSERT IGNORE INTO tags (tag_name ) VALUES ('$tag_name')";
                //Execute database query
                executeDatabase($databaseQuery);

                /*** get the tag ID from the db ***/
                $databaseQuery  = "SELECT tag_id FROM tags WHERE tag_name='$tag_name'";
                $result = executeDatabase($databaseQuery);
                $tag_id = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                /*** now insert the target ***/
                $databaseQuery = "INSERT INTO tag_targets
                    (tag_id, tag_target_name, tag_target_url, tag_type_id)
                    VALUES
                    ('$tag_id', '$tag_target_name', '$tag_target_url', '$tag_type_id')";
                executeDatabase($databaseQuery);
            }
}
```

So this function should take in the

```
tag_type_id

tag_target_name

tags_target_url 

tags
```

Then it inserts the `tag_name` into the table `tags`

Then retrieves the appropriate `tag_id` that goes with the `tag_name` to add it to the `tag_targets` table along with its respective data.

Everything is inserted into each of the tables correctly but nothing is being inserted into `tag_targets`

tag_target_name is currently set to take the filename of the uploaded image. Just to clear up any confusion.

Any ideas why this query would not be working correctly? Or is there a better way to do this for the sake of troubleshooting?

Added more to help explain my situation,

js gathering the form inputs

```
  //Create an empty container
    var path = "users/" + $("#username").val() + "/";
    var $elems = $();
    //Cycle thru the files
    $.each(data.files, function(idx, file) {
        //Create an input with attrs
        var $inputType = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'hidden',
            'value': '11',
            'id': 'tag_type_id', 
            'name': 'tag_type_id'
        });

        var $inputName = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'hidden',
            'value': file["name"],
            'id': 'tag_target_name', 
            'name': 'tag_target_name'
        });

        var $inputURL = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'hidden',
            'value': path + file["name"],
            'id': 'tag_target_url', 
            'name': 'tag_target_url'
        });    

        var $inputTags = $("<input/>", {
            'type': 'text',
            'placeholder': 'Separate tags with commas',
            'id': 'tags', 
            'name': 'tags' 
        });
```

This is my form collecting the information. After images are added to the drop zone the images are shown in thumbnails with one not hidden input field where the tags are added. 
The tags are properly being added to the database but the target_url table is not being populated.

```
  <div class="module">
            <div class="moduleTitle">Add Tags to Images</div> 
            <form onSubmit="addTags();return false;" id="tagAddForm">
            <ul>
        <!-- Ths is where the tag inputs will appear -->
        </ul>
             <input type="submit" name="login" value="Add New Tag" class="submit" id="login"/>
           </form>
        </div>
```

There are three tables,

```
tags
tag_id(auto increment) | tag_name(actual tag name)

tag_targets
tag_target_id(auto increment) | tag_id(from tags table) | tag_target_name(name of file) | tag_target_url(path to file) | tag_type_id(from tag_types table)

tag_types
tag_type_id(auto increment) | tag_type_name(tag class "image")
```

Comment: why the insert ignore

Comment: I used a tutorial to create this system and this is what it said, The tag engine also needs to check if a tag already exists in the tags table, as the tag names are UNIQUE and may not occur twice within the table. A simple SELECT query could be used to check if a tag is in the database,m and if it is, then continue to the next tag. But to save this added query, an INSERT IGNORE query can be used to ignore the error generate when a duplicate tag is found. The tag will not be INSERT'ed and the error will be IGNORE'ed.

Comment: This is the link, http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Tagging-With-PHP-And-MySQL.html I did convert this tutorial to work withmy ajax system so its not exact. But I designed the system around this tut.

Comment: just be weary of such a thing. Also dump out the value of $databaseQuery before the last call. See if is is loaded with that which has a chance of succeeding, as we know nothing about your schema or functions not shown

Comment: Ok, Its such a pain cause It's all done with ajax. Learned a valuable lesson on this one. I guess the only real way to troubleshoot this is rip the ajax out and post to the php file directly?

Comment: I am suggesting either a screen dump of your values, or perhaps an fopen as append to a log file so you have some way of debugging this thing. I cannot speak toward ripping out ajax or anything like that

Comment: Hey why you are storing `mysqli_num_rows($result);` in `$tag_id`, shouldn't it have been the actual tag Id you are fetching from the query

Comment: Yes that would make sense. Thank you for your input. I am very confused of how this is working and its so close.. I have never had to put together as complexed as this. Would you mind showing me what you think it should be and Ill try it? syntax wise?

Comment: or you mean just change it from tag_name to tag_id?

Comment: I added a lot more data with description. I am having trouble figuring out how to dump the data to a text file. I am trying to avoid ripping out ajax and posting directly to a php script but it's getting to the point where I am being lazy and I need to just do it.